# Como posso deixar metade de um lado de um elemento curvado para dentro como na figura com css?

Tags: html5, css3

[image]
Preciso fazer um menu exatamente igual ao da figura, o problema é que não consigo fazer a curva de baixo do elemento, de preferencia gostaria de fazer apenas com css, mas se não der, outra solução é aceita.

Comment: Desse jeito que você quer eu ainda não sei... só conheço o arredondamento de bordas com border-radius

Answer (score 6, accepted):

modo hard, faz no canvas, na unha e no dente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx=c.getContext('2d');

// preencher com a cor
ctx.beginPath();    
ctx.rect(65,2,534,150);
ctx.fillStyle="grey";
ctx.fill();

// linha de cima
ctx.beginPath(); 
ctx.lineWidth="2";
ctx.strokeStyle="black";
ctx.moveTo(65,1);
ctx.lineTo(600,1);
ctx.stroke();

// curva da esquerda
ctx.beginPath();    
ctx.arc(77,76,75,0.5*Math.PI,1.5*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();

// curva inferior
ctx.beginPath();    
ctx.arc(440,340,250,1*Math.PI,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle="white";
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();

// linha de baixo
ctx.beginPath();    
ctx.moveTo(65,149);  
ctx.lineTo(278,149);
ctx.stroke();

// linha da direita
ctx.moveTo(600,1);  
ctx.lineTo(600,146);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.font="25px Verdana";
ctx.fillText("Menu Item1",50,50);
ctx.fillText("Menu Item2",250,50);

window.onmousemove = function (event) { 
    var posX = event.clientX;
    var posY = event.clientY; 
    console.log('x='+posX+'   y='+posY);
    
    if ( (posX > 61 && posX <=206) && ( posY >= 43 && posY <= 57 ) ) {        
        ctx.fillStyle="blue";
        ctx.fillText("Menu Item1",50,50);
    }else{ 
        ctx.fillStyle="white";
        ctx.fillText("Menu Item1",50,50);
    }

};



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Para não deixar a resposta muito grande, os demais detalhes sobre os parametros e as funções você encontra nessa documentação:

**Edit:** A pedido da torcida coloquei um exemplo de como ficaria se ele fosse usado para ser um navbar, fiz meio que para exemplificar mesmo, se quiser que o evento click seja implementado ( pois eu fiz o onmousemove, seria basicamente a mesma coisa ) é só falar que edito denovo.

> http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

Comment: +1 pelo modo hard, no canvas, na unha e no dente"

Comment: Legal cara, mas o elemento tem que ser um nav, tem como fazer?

Comment: evento onmousemove já merece +1 ? ou só ganho se fazer o onclick ? rsrsrsr

Comment: A resposta do @SneepSNinjA  soluciona a pergunta original mais o requisito de transparência. É um excelente ponto inicial para você desenvolver o resto, Elder. Caso ainda tenha dúvidas, fique à vontade para iniciar uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda galera!

Answer (score 6):

2 soluções: Criando 3 elementos diferentes, ou 2 se você não se importar com positionamento absoluto.

**Solução 1:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Elemento 1 possui `border-radius` em todas as margens esquerdas, e `border-right-width: 0`;

Elemento 2 possui `border: 4px 4px 0 0`;

Elemento 3 é a chave: crie uma div que o contenha com o background cinza; faça com que o Elemento 3 tenha `background-color: white`; e ajuste os valores de `border-radius` das margens superiores.

**Solução 2**: Elementos 1 e 2 são um só, e 3 é posicionado (via `position:absolute; bottom:0;right:0;`) dentro.

```css
.container
{
  width:400px;
  height:80px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  }


.principal
{
  border:4px solid black;
  background-color:gray;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-radius:80px 0 0 80px;
  
}

.detalhe
{
  border:4px solid black;
  width:600px;
  height:600px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-590px;
  right:-220px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='principal'>
  </div>
  <div class='detalhe'>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Muito boa sua técnica, vou tentar me lembrar quando for fazer alguma div curvada, ficou bem mais simples assim

Comment: Boas soluções, mas preciso que essa parte curvada seja transparente. É possível?

Comment: Via imagem, ou utilizando o método descrito por @SneepSNinjA.

Comment: @SneepSNinjA É 'gambiarra' já que CSS não possui `border-style:inset` ainda, porém vi mais feias por aí. =)

Comment: kkkkkkkkk @OnoSendai é a metodologia usada http://www.gohorseprocess.com.br/extreme-go-horse-(xgh)

Comment: @OnoSendai me desculpe, eu me referi xgh a minha própria resposta.

Comment: @SneepSNinjA what? a minha tem um quê de XGH malandro de várzea também. =)